# Update the json file in android file

Tags: java, android, json

I am saving a json response inside my app using sharedPreference(`jsonObject.toString()`). It contains `JSONArray`, when the user updates some value of any one element, I wish to save the updated changes on the sharedPreference. Please help me for this task.

Example:-

```
{
  "locations": {
    "record": [
      {
        "id": 8817,
        "loc": "NEW YORK CITY"//update this as California and save the response
      },
      {
        "id": 2873,
        "loc": "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        "id": 1501
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is blocking you from replacing the whole string?

Comment: There are large number of records and ie object is containg about 1k records...

Comment: I see, but all  the same you should retrieve it, parse the json to update a single value.

Comment: it should be better to go with database if data is about 1k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to override the purpose of SharedPreferenecs,
It's purpose is to save primitive values such as strings integers or booleans, for simple use of single values, I wouldn't treat a Json **Array** as a single primitive value.

If I were you I would go with QuokMoon's offer with the Local Sqlite Database, this will allow you simple access for CRUD operations, the setup time is a bit longer, but the benefits you'll find are far beyond SharedPreferences.